# Modal shows up with an empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, axios, jsx

working on a project with ReactJS in which data gets pulled from their api and gets loaded as modal on the page, I want to display the table obtained through my api called by Axios, if I click on the button I get the Treemap displayed correctly but the table remains empty without the desired data :
`

```
const ChartSmallDoughnutChart3 = ({ aux, name, variable }) => {
  const { themeValues } = useSelector((state) => state.settings);
  const chartContainer = useRef(null);
  const legendRef = useRef(null);
  const [semiFullExample, setSemiFullExample] = useState(false);
  const [keywordsList, setKeywords] = useState();
  const [detailsList, setDetails] = useState();
  const couleur = 'rgb(75, 192, 192)';

  function timeout(delay) {
    return new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, delay));
  }

  const getDetails = async () => {
    const queryResult = await axios.post(GRAPHQL_API, {
      query: GET_KEYWORDS_DETAILS,
      variables: {
        company: name,
        category: variable,
      },
    });
    const result = queryResult.data.data.getDetailsKeyword;
    setDetails(result);
    console.log(result);
  };

  const handleModalLoad = async (param1, param2) => {
    const getKeywordsList = async () => {
      const queryResult = await axios.post(GRAPHQL_API, {
        query: GET_KEYWORDS_LIST,
        variables: {
          company: param1,
          category: param2,
        },
      });
      const result = queryResult.data.data.getKeywords;
      setKeywords(result);
    };
    getKeywordsList();
    setSemiFullExample(true);
    await timeout(1000);
    getDetails();
    // setSemiFullExample(true);
  };

const CustomSmallLegendDoughnutPlugin = React.useMemo(() => {
    return {
      id: 'htmlLegendDoughnutSmall',
      afterUpdate: (chart, args, options) => {
        const items = chart.options.plugins.legend.labels.generateLabels(chart);
        ReactDOM.render(
          <>
            {items.map((legend) => {
              const { strokeStyle, text, index, hidden } = legend;
              return (
                <div key={`customLegend${index}`}>
                  <div className="text-small text-muted text">{text}</div>
                  <Button variant="link" className="mb-1" onClick={() => handleModalLoad(name, variable)}>
                    {' '}
                    <div className="cta-3 text-info value">E Score</div>
                  </Button>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </>,
          legendRef.current
        );
      },
    };
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [name, variable]);

  return (
    <>
      <Row className="g-0 d-flex w-100">
        <Col ref={legendRef} className="sh-8 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center custom-legend-container" />
        <Col xs="auto">
          <canvas ref={chartContainer} className="sw-8 sh-8" />
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <Modal show={semiFullExample} onHide={() => setSemiFullExample(false)} size="semi-full" scrollable centered>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>E Score Details</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <TreemapChart aux={keywordsList} color={couleur} />
          <section className="scroll-section" id="stripedRows">
            <>
              <h2 className="small-title">ESG Details</h2>
              <Table striped>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Paragraph</th>
                    <th scope="col">Link</th>
                    <th scope="col">Topic</th>
                    <th scope="col">Keywords</th>
                    <th scope="col">Key-Words</th>
                    <th scope="col">Sentiment</th>
                    <th scope="col">Sentiment Score</th>
                    <th scope="col">Paraphrase</th>
                    <th scope="col">Topic Score</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {detailsList?.map((item, i) => (
                    <tr key={i}>
                      <td>{item.Paragraph}</td>
                      <td>{item.Link}</td>
                      <td>{item.Topic}</td>
                      <td>{item.keywords}</td>
                      <td>{item.key_words}</td>
                      <td>{item.Sentiment}</td>
                      <td>{item.Sentiment_Score}</td>
                      <td>{item.Paraphrase}</td>
                      <td>{item.Topic_Score}</td>
                    </tr>
                  ))}
                </tbody>
              </Table>
            </>
          </section>
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button onClick={() => setSemiFullExample(false)}>Close</Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};
```

`
When launching Modal, DetailsList remains empty and there is no data despite the API returning the data correctly.

As you can see, when I click on the "div" of "E Score" the HandleModalLoad function will be executed

[Modal Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8jJU.png)

[API Result with Axios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WCP1.png)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: where is the function handleModalLoad called?

Comment: detailsList state is empty and data is not displayed because function handleModalLoad is not called which is supposed to call function getDetails and getDetails will set the state

Comment: yes it exists in the code block, you can find it :)